# xts Column name suggestions are not displayed in RStudio

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio, xts

For example, if I have an `xts` object `object.xts`,  when I type

```
object.xts$
```

within RStudio, I don't receive the column name suggestion dropdown or autocomplete.  I was wondering why this happens for other objects, but not `xts`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is because there is no `.DollarNames.xts` method. Try it after you copy/paste this function into your R session:

```
.DollarNames.xts <- function(x, pattern = "") {
  grep(pattern, colnames(x), value = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I sourced the function, but no luck.  Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: It worked fine for me at the terminal. I don't have an RStudio install handy to test for myself.